# IIS 7.0 increase the URL size limit

Tags: php, url, iis, get

I have a web page that receives notification from payment processor when a client has made a payment to my site.

The notification arrives in the form of a GET submission, so the URL can be quite long. I have no jurisdiction over how the notification is sent, so I cannot simply change it to a POST submission, which would solve all my problems.

The problem is that sometimes the notification is not received as the URL is too long. It is only barely clipping the limit of what is allowed because if I shorten the URL by a mere 15 characters I get a successful connection.

I have tried changing UrlSegmentMaxCount om the windows registry, but the problem remains.

Does anyone know how I can configure my IIS hosted php site to allow for longer GET requests?

**EDIT**

This is what I have tried.

In case it is a php issue I have added the line in my .htaccess file:

```
php_value suhosin.get.max_value_length 2048
```

and to try and fix any windows issues I have put in my registry: #

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters]
>   "UrlSegmentMaxLength"=dword:00001000

Comment: Are you sure the problem is IIS and not PHP?

Comment: Well, actually, no, I am not. Can you suggest how I would go about checking my PHP limitations?

Comment: Counting the characters there are 2081 which would imply that it is hitting a 2000 character limit

Comment: Is [request filtering](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits#005) enabled? `maxQueryString` and `maxUrl` might be a restriction if it is.

Comment: IIS does not use `.htaccess` files, it uses `web.config` instead.

Comment: @FDL good call. I went into 'Edit Request Filtering Services' and doubled the 'Maximum URL length' and 'Maximum query string' parameters solved the problem. If you want to add your comment as an answer Ill accept it as solution.

Comment: @KevinBradshaw added as an answer - glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is [request filtering](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits#005) enabled? If it is try changing the `maxQueryString` and `maxUrl` parameters and see if that's what's restricting you.

Comment: To solve the problem: in IIS ->  clicked on my site under 'Sites' in the left Connection pane -> dbl clicked on Request Filtering (under IIS in main content pane) -> Under 'Actions' in the right hand window pane clicked 'Edit Feature Settings' -> Doubled the 'Maximum URL length' and 'Maximum query string' in the resulting pop up.

Comment: Check if you have any word like "Select", "Update", "Delete" in the Query string. You could have a "Filtering Rule" called "SQL_INJECTION_MITIGATION" that would be blocking the pop up.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the **maxUrlLength** setting in your web.config file. If not defined, you can increase the maximun number of allowed characters in a URL with a httpRuntime setting:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="500" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This would increase the default of 260 characters to 500.

(source: http://www.saotn.org/the-length-url-request-exceeds-configured-maxurllength-value/) - used "Answer" to add the web.config configuration code.

Comment: Good call, but unfortunately the problem remains

Comment: @KevinBradshaw would it be possible to post an example, either here or on pastebin? Perhaps I can reproduce the issue in a test-environment.

Comment: thanks for the offer, but the problem was solved by changing parameters in Request Filtering.

Comment: @KevinBradshaw great you solved it. Please update your question or add an answer. Did it had something to do with [requestfiltering/requestlimits](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits)

Comment: I have asked @FDL to upgrade his comment to an answer in order to accept it, if he does not wish to do so I will add answer myself.